# Why STP has to be disable on Trunk Ports?

Tags: switch, spanning-tree, trunk, switchport

I have 5 Switches on a Private Network 10.0.0.0/8 with 8 Vlans. On Access ports is running Rapid STP.  On Trunk Ports between Switches should i disable STP or not? 
I would be very pleased if someone can explain why.

Comment: Are you maybe thinking of spanning-tree portfast, and why that's not suggested to be on, on trunk ports?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

You should not disable spanning tree on trunk interfaces. In fact, STP needs to be on links between the switches, which should be the trunk interfaces.

You can also leave STP enabled on the access interfaces to prevent loops if someone connects two access interfaces.

Look at it this way: if the links between the switches are not running STP, and somehow you have a loop, then your network will painfully die due to a broadcast storm. Recovering from a broadcast storm is not easy, and it usually involves shutting down switches or pulling connections until it stops, then you need to find the loop and break it before resuming normal operation.

Comment: A small addition: using RSTP between switches enables you to run redundant links between switches in case a links fails. MSTP even allows you to productively use those redundant links for defined VLANs.

Comment: Firstly, RSTP is running on all our switches, because there is some kind of devices that do not support all kind of STP. Secondly, my network manager told me that spanning tree root-guard and spanning tree admin-edge-port has to be disabled on trunk ports. Is it that STP is disabled?? Or is it anything else???